# Gradle takes long to initialize

Tags: gradle

I am trying to figure out why gradle build takes seconds before it starts the build. When I run build it takes almost 10 seconds before anything is printed really. This was not happening in the past with older versions (dunno when it changed) and it might be related to windows 10 or antivirus but I was curious whether there is a way to tell what is happening there.

Here is what I came up with

- it is the same for wrapper and direct execution of gradle
- below log is with --debug flag. it takes about a second before first line is printed. What is the more than 3s gap before "Executing build"?

```
2021-02-15T10:49:53.835+0100 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Initialized native services in: C:\Users\username\.gradle\native
2021-02-15T10:49:53.916+0100 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction] 
#############################################################################
   WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING

   Debug level logging will leak security sensitive information!

   https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/logging.html#sec:debug_security
#############################################################################

2021-02-15T10:49:53.962+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files integration is not available. Continuing with fallback.
2021-02-15T10:49:57.197+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Executing build f3347a0e-2f9e-4b6b-abcd-b720fb6a167d in daemon client {pid=15440}
...
```

Got reinstalled system to no avail, trying to get antivirus temporarily disabled to test impact but that is corporate nightmare... Any ideas?